# Condition in query parameter of <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My goal is change the whole query depending on some parameter in this.props.
But this doesn't work:

```
<Link to={`/someurl`} query= ({this.props.type} == 'type1') ? {{ page: 1}} : {{group: 2 }} </Link>
```

neither this works:

```
<Link to={`/someurl`} query= {(this.props.type == 'type1') ? {{ page: 1}} : {{group: 2 }}} </Link>
```

I tried other few possible variants, but still didn't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`` <Link to={`/someurl`} query= {this.props.type === 'type1' ? { page: 1} : {group: 2 }}>some text</Link> ``